# Can I setup redirects with Modsec?

Tags: apache-2.4, mod-security

The web servers I managed are all running Apache 2.4 with Modsec. Is it possible to write a rule that will serve up a different page if matched by Modsec? I want this to be independent of the domain.

For example, if domain1.com/login or domain2.com/login redirect to domain3.com.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can, use the [redirect](https://github.com/SpiderLabs/ModSecurity/wiki/Reference-Manual-%28v2.x%29#redirect) action.

For example:

```
SecRule REQUEST_URI "/login" "phase:1,id:52,status:302,redirect:https://domain3.com
```

Though if doing a straight redirect like above you’d be better doing this in Apache.

Comment: This looks like it will work. How would you accomplish this with Apache? It needs to cover the whole server, some of them have thousands of sites on them.

Comment: Don’t understand why that would be an issue. You could rewrite URLs using mod_alias’s `redirect` or `redirectMatch` (https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_alias.html) or for more complicated rules use mod_rewrite (https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_rewrite.html).